# preg_match_all doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I want to get matches on a webpage based on following regular expression: 
(.*)
I tested it on regexpal.com (an online regular expression test tool) and it works fine. 
However, when I use it in php, I can't find any matches. The statement I use in php is

```
preg_match_all("/<a href=\"\/title\/.*\/\">(.*)<\/a>/", $content, $matches);
```

I checked the $content, it's correct. So is there anything wrong from my statement? Thanks!

Comment: Weird. Can you show the example of actual HTML that should be covered by that regex?

Comment: Please don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use the PHP DOM module. http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Please, please... for the love of God, don't wrap Regular Expressions that deal with URLs or HTML in /.** You have to escape it all over the place. It's terrible. Look here:

```
preg_match_all('~<a href="/title/[^">]+/">(.*?)</a>~si', $content, $matches);
```

1. **Single quotes**. No longer need to escape double quotes. Why would you use double quotes when you don't have expandable "{$variables}"?
2. **Wrap RegExp into any non reserved character**. For URLs and HTML / is the worst choice as it drags you to escape redundancy hell.
3. **Use 'si' as flags** in HTML as tags can be multiline and .+? or .*? match multi line by default. And you need case insensitivity.
4. **Avoid using .+? in attributes**. You may capture entire tags. Add break characters too. See my pattern above... so you don't over do it if HTML is broken.

*There's more ways to improve this but this should do it.*

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is SO GOOD.  Lots of really good regex tips, The last three are actionable outside of php as well.  This should be the accepted answer, if it works(which I suspect it does).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your regex pattern lazy (non-greedy) by adding `?` >>

```
preg_match_all("/<a href=\"\/title\/.*?\/\">(.*?)<\/a>/", $content, $matches);
```

Comment: @Adam - Not needed to escape `=`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/<a href\=\"\/title\/.*\/\">(.*?)<\/a>/", $content, $matches);
```

I would try:

```
preg_match_all('/<a href\=".title.*">(.*?)<\/a>/', $content, $matches);
```

for brevity.